# Can I use a compound primary key as foreign key in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I just wanted to know if it is possible to use table A's compound primary key within table B as a foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE A(
   ID INT,
   COD INT,
   CONSTRAINT  PK_INF PRIMARY KEY (ID, COD),
);

CREATE TABLE B(
   REF_NUMBER INT,
   NAME VARCHAR(30),
   CONSTRAINT  FK_INF FOREIGN KEY (REF_NUMBER) REFERENCES A(PK_INF) <- is this correct?
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "yes", you can use a compound primary key for a foreign key reference.  But, you need two columns for it.  Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE A(
   ID INT,
   COD INT,
   CONSTRAINT  PK_INF PRIMARY KEY (ID, COD),
);

CREATE TABLE B(
   REF_ID INT,
   REF_CODINT,
   NAME VARCHAR(30),
   CONSTRAINT  FK_INF FOREIGN KEY (REF_ID, REF_COD) REFERENCES A(ID, COD) <- is this correct?
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought I would only need to write the alias I used for the primary key in A into B's reference.

Comment: @ditmark12 . . . The reference is through the columns themselves   The name of the constraint is not really that useful, except for dropping the constraint.